# Create a timeout in an SCXML state machine

Tags: state-machine, scxml

In an [SCXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/) state machine, how can I say *"Fire an event 3 minutes after I enter this state, but not if I sit in the state for 2.9 minutes and then leave. If I re-enter the state, restart the timer (don't go off in 0.1 minutes)"*

Comment: +1 Informative. What platform do you use for SCXML?

Comment: @MM. I'm currently using [my own interpreter](https://github.com/Phrogz/LXSC) which runs on Lua on [custom hardware](http://shield.nvidia.com/). (This Lua-based interpreter may be replaced by a custom C++ one for speed in the near future.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`<send>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#send) to fire a delayed event (with any name, e.g. "timeout") when you enter the state, and use [`<cancel>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#cancel) when you exit the state to remove the timer. You must make sure that you create a unique ID for each `<send>` instance that you plan to later cancel.

```xml
<scxml xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml' version='1.0'>
  <state id="s1">
    <onentry><send id="state1-timer" event="timeout" delay="180s"/></onentry>
    <onexit><cancel sendid="state1-timer"/></onexit>
  </state>
  <!-- ... --->
</scxml>
```

<sub>*Note: you can only use either `s` (seconds) or `ms` (milliseconds) for the delay duration, per the [CSS2 time spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/syndata.html#q20). Thus, 3 minutes is `180s`.*</sub>

Comment: Just a note for future users ... the answer above is close but not exact.  
See http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-scxml-20060124/  
in the send, change id to sendid. It will send just fine, but that sets the ID for the cancel - it will not cancel correctly. I didn't realize this until I was walking the scheduler code and it wasn't triggering!  
<onentry><send sendid="state1-timer" event="timeout" delay="180s"/></onentry>

Comment: @EvanReynolds Your comment is based on an old working draft of the SCXML spec. Per the [candidate recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#send), the `<send>` element has an `id` attribute, not a `sendid` attribute. (And, the `<cancel>` element [uses a `sendid` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#cancel).)

Comment: It was current when I wrote the comment. :-) Thank you for the updated information, that is good to know!